# Angular JS: ng-repeat is not updated inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When I update the data in the variable $scope.userMovies, ng-repeat does not update if inside a ng-view. Outside ng-view it gets updated correctly.

What am I missing that ng-repeat does not work as I expect?

**UPDATE:**
As requested I moved the code to Plunker to better undestand my problem:
[Plunker Code Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NqFTgzxYs33qQSGWCpA7)

**UPDATE:**
Solved saving the variable userMovies in the rootScope.

Comment: Could you provide a plunker or a fiddle of this issue?

Comment: Are you initializing userMovies to anything before the `getMoviesByTitle` call happens?

Comment: Yes I am initializing userMovies in the controller, see updated example on plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ng-view](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angView) creates its own scope.  What is likely happening is that you are creating $scope property `userMovies` on this ng-view child scope, which your MovieboxCtrl scope can not see/access.  As @darkporter alluded to in a comment, your MovieboxCtrl should create an empty `userMovies` array.  Then when the MovieCtrl sets `userMovies`, it will update the existing object reference, rather than create a new property.

---

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzosUqBIDHpGvi7Y7Oid?p=preview) that stores the data in the service, rather than in a controller.

```
angular.module('moviebox.services', [])
  .factory('movieboxApi', function() {
    var model = { movies: [] };
    model.getMoviesByTitle = function(query) {
      angular.copy([{'title': 'foo'},{'title': 'foo1'},
      {'title': 'foo2'},{'title': 'foo3'},
      {'title': 'foo4'}], model.movies);
    };
    return model;
  });
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, movieboxApi) {
    $scope.getMoviesByTitle = function() {
      movieboxApi.getMoviesByTitle($scope.query);
    };
    $scope.userMovies = movieboxApi.movies;
});
app.controller('MovieboxCtrl', function ($scope, movieboxApi) {
    $scope.userMovies = movieboxApi.movies;
});
```

HTML change:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

`angular.copy()` is used because the controllers have a reference to the `model.movies` array that the service initially created.  We want to modify that array, not assign a new one.

Comment: I'm already initializing userMovies in the controller. Do I have to initialize elsewhere?

Comment: @Codingmonkey, when you click the "Go" button, the getMoviesByTitle() function associated with the MovieboxCtrl on line 23 of your index.html file is being called.  It populates the $scope associated with that controller.  Inside ng-view, another MovieboxCtrl (and another $scope) are created.  Changes you make to one scope are not visible in the other.

Comment: So if I want the ng-repeat to react to changes when clicking "go", the button have to be inside the ng-view partial, so that it uses the same controller and scope?

Comment: @Codingmonkey, I suggest you save your data in your service, then have your controllers access the data via the service.  See my updated answer and plunker.